# Get ChildComponents deep in the whole Component-hierachy

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I want to get all `ChildComponents` from my `ParentComponent` in Angular. Problem is that the `ChildComponents` are not directly a child of the `ParentComponent`, but a child of some other components which themselves are a child of the parent component.

Example template:

```
<parent>
    <child>Child 1</child>
    <another_component>
        <child>Child 2</child>
    </another_component>
</parent>
```

My parent Component:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

@ContentChildren(ChildComponent) entrys: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

constructor() {

}

ngOnInit() {

}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.entrys.toArray().forEach(component => {
    // here is only Child 1
  });
}
```

As you can see only Child 1 is in the QueryList in the end, but I need Child 2 to be there aswell.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren), you can't "retrieve elements or directives that are in other components' templates, since a component's template is always a black box to its ancestors."

In `AnotherComponent` you would need:

```js
@ContentChildren(ChildComponent) entries: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

...

getEntries(): ChildComponent[] {
  return this.entries.toArray();
}
```

And in `ParentComponent`:

```js
@ContentChild(AnotherComponent) anotherComponent: AnotherComponent;
@ContentChildren(ChildComponent) entries: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const entries = this.entries.toArray().concat(this.anotherComponent.getEntries());
  entries.forEach(component => {
    // Your code.
  });
}
```

Comment: Problem is that I do have more then one AnotherComponent. Also sometimes the hierachy is even deeper so e.g. the child component is in componentC, which is in componentB, which is in componentA, which is in parentComponent. Is there maybe another possibility?

Comment: Maybe I do not need the whole component, I just want to run a method of ChildComponent.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to get all the child components if you don't know where they will be in the component tree. What are you trying to achieve? You may want to use a service instead to run your method.

Comment: Otherwise you'll need a chain of `@Output`s and `@Input`s down your component hierarchy, though this could become unwieldy if you have a lot.

Comment: Exatly this is very unwieldy.
So I want to make a component called MyFormComponent. And in this I have multiple InputComponents. And the MyFormComponent has a method validate(). And this methode should call all validate() methods from the InputComponents.

Comment: Then I would suggest seeing if you can refactor to call your method from a common service.

Comment: Good idea, I will do it like this :)